# upload audio files to s3 bucket using signature and policy in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS S3. How can I upload file directly to s3 bucket from android using aws policy and signature?

Comment: 1. Please format your question. 2. I don't see your actual question.

Comment: i want try to upload audio files to s3 server by using policy and signature  with out sdk of s3 or ,s3upload service